# Keepass (KeePassXC) key file question

Tags: keepass

What is the difference between a keyfile generated by KeePass and a keyfile that is chosen to be "any file" on the computer?
"Any file" must have completely the same hash in order to unlock the database. It must be an unedited file, including timestamp, etc.

Now I have opened the keyfile generated by KeePass(XC) in a text editor and can see that it is actually a text file, as an instruction.

My question about the keyfile generated by KeePass:

- Does it mean that the instruction is what matters and not the file itself as is the case with "any file"?
- Does it mean that I can re-create it on another machine without actually having a verbatim copy of the key file?

Comment: The question addresses specifically keyfiles (.keyx), not database itself (.kdbx).